# In Java, how do I take the values of a 2D array and store them in another 2D array with different column and row size?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am doing a project where I have to make a matrices from a 2D array. One of the requirements is to covert a 3x4 2D array (with values stored in) to a 6x2 2d array (with the same values)?

```
public int[][] covertMatrix(int[][] ma, int r, int c) {
        rw = r;
        col = c;

        this.ma = new int[rw][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < rw; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                ma[i][j] = ma[i][j];    
            }
        }
        return ma;
}
```

I've tried this code and it reshapes the array but only prints a 2D array of zeroes.

Comment: You probably wanted `this.ma[i][j] = ma[i][j];`

Comment: I've tried that and it gives me an ArrayIndexOutofBoundException error for that line. @Eran

Comment: of course, you are iterating on the dimensions of the new array while reading the content of the old one. It works for the first three rows but fail on the 4th one. The main question, is how do you want the items of the array to be sorted in the new one? You just need the same elements or do you need them in a specific order?

Comment: @Wisthler I need them in a specific order of 1 3 4 2 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Comment: that order does not make any sense for me, you just have the number 2 out of sequence and then what, you fill in the new matrix row by rw in that order? column by column?

Comment: @Wisthler I don't think the order is important, it was just an example the professor gave us as to how he did it: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 will be fine for the order

Comment: @Klion ok, I've added a draft of code to show you how I would have done it, have a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a starting matrix of 3x4 like

```
+--+--+--+--+
|01|02|03|04|
+--+--+--+--+
|05|06|07|08|
+--+--+--+--+
|09|10|11|12|
+--+--+--+--+
```

that you want to convert in a 6x2 matrix like

```
+--+--+
|01|02|
+--+--+
|03|04|
+--+--+
|05|06|
+--+--+
|07|08|
+--+--+
|09|10|
+--+--+
|11|12|
+--+--+
```

To do that, clearly `tab1[i][j] = tab2[i][j]` will not work. You need to translate address between the two arrays. At first sight, using the modulo for the row and the rest of the division for the col would do the trick.

Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] tab1 = new int[][]{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab1));
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        int size = tab1.length * tab1[0].length;
        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++){
            int j = size % i;
            if(j == 0){
                convert(tab1, i, size/i);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void convert(int[][] tab1, int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(String.format("converting to %dx%d", row, col));
        int[][] tab2 = new int[row][col];
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
                int index = i*col + j;
                int newRow = index / tab1[0].length;
                int newCol = index % tab1[0].length;
                tab2[i][j] = tab1[newRow][newCol];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab2));
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
    }
```

Which give the output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
---------------------------
converting to 1x12
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
---------------------------
converting to 2x6
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
---------------------------
converting to 3x4
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
---------------------------
converting to 4x3
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
---------------------------
converting to 6x2
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
---------------------------
converting to 12x1
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]]
---------------------------
```

Comment: What if the user is able to change the dimensions of the array?

Comment: this will work as long as the number of cells (3*4 = 6*2 = 12) are the same. So, 12*1, 4*3, 2*6, 1*12 would work too. It can be upgraded to be more flexible/robust but that wasn't part of your initial question so I kept it simple

Comment: It works and I wanted to know how could i use the user input (passed in as r and c in my code) to change the columns size and row size between 6x2, 2x6, 3x4, and 4x3? @Wisthler

Comment: so, you receive c and r and in the method and you create the new array with that size and the conditions in my loops are based on the array dimensions so it should work directly (once the typo on the first condition reading the original array size instead of the new one is fixed)

Comment: Which typo would that be? I'm not sure which line you are referring to. @Wisthler

Comment: just updated the code,  added all the size in it dinamically and showing the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188538/discussion-between-klion-and-wisthler).

Answer (score 1):

You can change your method to :

```
public int[][] covertMatrix(int[][] ma, int r, int c) {
   int trans[][] = new int[r][c]; 
   int count = 0;  // used to increment the list elements

   // fetch all elements from the original array 'ma'
   List<Integer> collectList = Arrays.stream(ma).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                                     .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

   // assign the values from the list to resp array indices
   for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
           trans[i][j] = collectList.get(count);
           count++;
       }
   }

   return trans;
}
```

Logic :

1. Create a 2D array of your required dimensions, here `trans` with `r` and `c`.
2. Now collect all the elements of the array `ma` to a list `collectList`
3. Iterate over the newly created array, fetch the values from the list and assign them to the respective indices.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Collectors?

Comment: @kilon: Yes. Just iterate over the array received and store it in a list using 2 for-loops. Like : `for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < ma[0].length; j++) {
    collectList.add(ma[i][j]);
   }
  }`

Comment: @kai: No. To store it in the list you need the dimensions of the array passed in. To get the number of rows we use `ma.length` and for the number of columns we need `ma[0].length`.

Comment: The question clearly states that OP wants to transform an array of `3X4` into `6X2`, not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have tried both ways and the same error appears or it doesn't change the matrix at all. If i run my previous code it would print the array in 6x2 but the values would all be 0's.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the code similar to what i have above but I just cant figure out a way to get the arrays values

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you. I have run the same exact code on my machine and it does convert the array to a `6X2`. How are you invoking it?

Comment: And just FYI, the answer you've accepted does include more changes to your original code! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This version redistributes the values to the new array.

Calculating the indexes by dividing the cellindex by the colums which gives the row and calculating the rest wich gives to new column.

```
public int[][] covertMatrix(int[][] ma, int r, int c) {
    rw = r;
    col = c;
    int element = 0;
    int[][] ma2 = new int[rw][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ma[i].length; j++) {
           final int newRow = (element)/col; //integer division ignoring rest.
           final int newCol = (element)%col; // rest of the division.
           ma2[newRow][newCol] = ma[i][j];
           element++;
        }
    }
    this.ma = ma2;
    return ma2;
}



System.err.println(Arrays.deepToString(covertMatrix(new int[][]{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}},6,2)));
-> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
```